# php using more then one array in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

in controller i send the object to view like:

```
public function comapre_array()
{

 $data['pro1']="result from model";   //product details

 $data['pro2']="result from model";   //product details

 $data['pro3']="result from model";   //product details

  $this->load->view('user/product_comp',$data);
}
```

and in my view i need to display that in table to comparison,

i need to take the three array value in single loop using foreach,is it is possible,

i tried like this

```
foreach($pro1 as $m,$pro2 as $n,$pro3 as $o){
    //printing values
}

but it shows error,
```

please suggest me is there is any other ideas to implement this,

Comment: You already have the data you need in `$data`. Just loop over it, all the values are there. And no, you can't do what you suggested.

Comment: can you please show the method to print the data inside $data

Comment: [print_r](http://php.net/print_r) seems to work nice. Consider reading some tutorials or watching a few videos about basic things in php.

Comment: thanks for your information, i know print_r print all those things in array i don't want these explanation. i need to get all those record in single table to compare the products, if you know the method please otherwise i don't need any irrelevant ans.

Answer (score 1):

Make your data set as,

```
$data['product']['pro1']="result from model";   //product details
$data['product']['pro2']="result from model";   //product details
$data['product']['pro3']="result from model";   //product details
```

Basically put your products under a new array key called `product`.

And in your view, get the `$product` first and loop it.

```
foreach( $product as $prod_key => $prod_value ){
    // $prod_key = pro1, pro2, pro3
    // $prod_value = product details
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If your different arrays have the same key structure you could do something like that :

```
foreach($pro1 as $key => $pro){


    if(isset($pro2[$key],$pro3[$key])) {
        //print your values here
    } else {
        //Your arrays don't have the same key structure
    }

}
```